# Update Information Outdated (conflicting message?)

Tags: 12.04, updates, update-manager

I get this alert and it says that:

> The update information is outdated. This may be caused by network problems or py a repository that is no longer available. Please update manually by clicking on this icon and then selection 'Check for updates' and checking if some of the listed repositories fail.

But when I check out for updates it says everything is updated already but the red alert is still there, is there a problem with Ubuntu?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is usually caused by a problem with a repository (as the message states). Try to manually disable ppa's until this problem is solved.

Guide to disabling repositories:

1. start Ubuntu Software Center
2. click edit in the top bar and go to software sources
3. Select 'other sources' in the top bar of the new window
4. deselect any of the ppa's which could be the cause of this problem (the more 'fishy' ppa's)

I had this caused once by a ppa for canon drivers, just to give a idea as to what you are searching for.